# Stop function from loading items multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build an if statement to stop this function from loading the items multiple times. The issue starts at the let x=-1 variable. It is adding all the items over 10 times.

```
function getRecordUI( alias, type, id, viewtype, version ) {

    // Get record model from Data Model Registry
    if ( type ) {
        getJSONUIModel( type,
            function ( data ) {
                displayRecordSections( alias, type, id, version, viewtype, data );
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting UI model for type " + type);
                console.log(error);
                displayRecordSections( alias, type, id, version, viewtype, null );
            });
    } else {
        displayRecordSections( alias, type, id, version, viewtype, null );
    }
    let x = -1;
    lastName = "";
    $("#panels-region .panel-heading").each(function () {
        x++

        console.log($(this))
        let curName = $(this).attr("name")
        $('<a id="panels-sidebar-' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter("#panels-sidebar" + lastName.replace(/ |\//g, "_"))
        console.log($(this).attr("name"), lastName)
        lastName = "-" + curName
    })

    $("#graph-region .panel-heading h4").each(function () {
        x++
        let x = -1;
        console.log($(this).text())
        let curName = $(this).text().replace("Collapse panelExpand panel", "")
        $('<a id="tree_viewers-sidebar-' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter("#tree_viewers-sidebar" + lastName.replace(/ |\//g, "_"))
        console.log($(this).attr("name"), lastName)
        lastName = "-" + curName
    })

    $(".menu-links a").css("padding", "0px 8px")
    $(".panel-body").css("background-color", "white")
    $("#panels-region .panel-wrapper .panel-default").css("background-color", "white")

}
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like where you are finding `$("#graph-region .panel-heading h4")`?

Comment: Just a large block of HTML data. Am I answering this correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML code, I would guess that the JQuery is finding 10 instances of $("#graph-region .panel-heading h4") and looping through the output that many times.

So if your HTML looks something like:

```
<div id='graph-region' class='panel-heading'></div>
<div id='graph-region' class='panel-heading'></div>
<div id='graph-region' class='panel-heading'></div>
<div id='graph-region' class='panel-heading'></div>
<div id='graph-region' class='panel-heading'></div>
```

it will run

```
$("#panels-region .panel-heading").each(function () {
    ...your code
}
```

5 times.

If you're looking to only run it once, you'll have to use something other than the `.each`. Probably something like

```
let element = $("#panels-region .panel-heading").first()
```

and then execute the code you used to build your anchor tag with `element`.

Comment: The function to create the panels in the code is running multiple times, so each time it runs it places the items. I need them to place once and not run again

Comment: An easy fix for that would be to just have a boolean outside the function scope that makes the function return after it's been toggled.

Comment: Can you give an example for me, please

Comment: added let element = $("#panels-region .panel-heading").first(index) {
x++
if(index === 0) {
my code

and it is not working, any idea on what might be wrong here?

Comment: Not sure where you would be getting index from? If you haven't declared `index` anywhere, it will always default to false.